# How to Programmatically detect if airplane mode is on within an ionic app

Tags: javascript, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I want to display a popup alert to the user when the app has entered the airplane mode. I tried using `@ionic-native/network` package to detect if the device is connected to the internet or not. `this.network.type` cannot detect if the device has entered the airplane mode.

Comment: probably not possible. but you should be able to detect if the device has internet connection, which should be just as good.

Answer (score 0):

This is a cordova question and not particular to Ionic.

It is possible on Android though it requires root.
https://github.com/RodrigoGontijo/Cordova-Plugin-AirPlaneMode

You may also want to consider https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-open-native-settings